# Terminology for a rectangle whose width/height ratio is between $r$ and $1/r$?

Tags: geometry, terminology

What do you call a rectangle whose width/height ratio is between $r$ and $1/r$?

I use the terminology "$r$-balanced rectangle". So, a $1$-balanced rectangle is a square, a $2$-balanced rectangle is a rectangle whose width/height ratio is between $1/2$ and $2$, etc., and an $\infty$-balanced rectangle is just any general rectangle.

Is there a more standard terminology?

Comment: I've replaced the word "notation" with "terminology"; to me at least, "notation" specifically refers to symbols, whereas terminology refers to words.

Comment: Why is that useful? It only makes sense to introduce terminology if you use something frequently and better even, if it's a fundamental concept. If it turns out to be fundamental in your work, go ahead and give it a name. But I've never encountered this elsewhere and I can't fathom what purpose it could serve.

Comment: Never seen anything that needed the introduction of such terminology.

Comment: I think it would be naïve to close this question just because no-one who has read this question has ever come across such a thing before. That is to say, noone who has read it known the answer...which is a flawed reason for closing! For all we know, these things do have a name and we just do not know it - and so we have a valid question...

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Yes, I use this concept frequently in my research, that is why I ask...

Comment: @user1729 : However, until OP has provided us the context of why he even needs the terminology to begin with, I think the question is just too localized and for that reason, I voted to close.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: You could go through the list of questions the OP asked to see example applications, e.g. in [rectangularizing the square](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/411690/35416).

Comment: @MvG: Questions apparently so general he has to answer them himself. It's his question, if he's not going to make the effort to make it understandable or interesting to us, he should not be expecting us to put any effort into answering it.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: It is a terminology question - no effort is needed by an answerer, and no the OP should not be required to give motivation!

Comment: @MvG thank you!

Just to give some motivation: my research is related to division of land resources between people. One of the reasonable constraints in dividing land resources is that each land plot should be a balanced rectangle, because an un-balanced rectangle (i.e. a very skinny or a very flat one) is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest term I could find so far is **fat rectangles**. This term has some applications in computer geometry. See, for example:

- Agarwal et al, Binary Space Partitions for Fat Rectangles, 2000
- Tóth, Binary Space Partitions for Axis-Aligned Fat Rectangles, 2008

Links: http://www.citeulike.org/user/erelsegal-halevi/tag/fat-rectangles

Answer (score 0):

The term "aspect ratio" is sometimes used.  By convention it is always bigger than 1, i.e. one always divides the longer side by the shorter.  Then your 2-balanced rectangles have aspect ratio at most 2.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a terminology for a rectangle whose aspect ratio is at most 2. The references I found call it "2-fat rectangle".